# Spark sql how to execute sql command in a loop for every record in input DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Spark sql how to execute sql command in a loop for every record in input DataFrame

I have a DataFrame with following schema

```
     %> input.printSchema
        root
        |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
        |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

I have another DataFrame on which I need to execute sql command

```
        val testtable = testDf.registerTempTable("mytable")

        %>testDf.printSchema
            root
            |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)

        sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT * from mytable WHERE _1=$id").show()
```

$id should be from the input DataFrame and the sql command should execute for all input table ids

Comment: You probably want to do an `inner join` between both tables using different keys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can work with a single new DataFrame containing all the rows present in `testDf` that matches the values present in the `id` column of `input`, you can do an inner join operation, as stated by Alberto:

```
val result = input.join(testDf, input("id") == testDf("_1"))
result.show()
```

Now, if you want a new, different DataFrame for each distinct value present in `testDf`, the problem is considerably harder. If this is the case, I would suggest you to make sure the data in your lookup table can be collected as a local list, so you could loop through its values and create a new DataFrame for each one as you already thought (this **is not recommended**):

```
val localArray: Array[Int] = input.map { case Row(_, id: Integer) => id }.collect
val result: Array[DataFrame] = localArray.map {
  i => testDf.where(testDf("_1") === i)
}
```

Anyway, unless the lookup table is very small, I suggest that you adapt your logic to work with the single joined DataFrame of my first example.

Comment: That's correct ,I want new different DataFrame for each distinct value in testDf. As I have to do a join with reference DataFrame to get the final output.